# Suggestions for storing private user content lists

Tags: 7, nodes, users, views

I have a feature on my Drupal7 site where users can store a list of personal stock symbols (NYSE, NASDAQ, etc) and then do different actions on that list; quote, chart, etc. These lists are private to each user.
For the first iteration, using a custom module, I've stored them in a custom table after the user enters them using the Drupal Form API. The form has a text box for list title, and a text area for entering symbols separated by space or comma. They can have multipe lists by clicking a 'add more' button. The data is stored in a flat structure of "-list_title1 sym1 sym2... -list_title2 sym1 sym2..." It is then split out for use in the UI. Some users have more than 300 symbols.

For the second iteration I would like to be able to store these symbols so that they can be referenced individually (deleted or added, notes about symbol) and the lists sortable. I would like to be able to utilize Views and features like Draggable_views so that the symbols could be re-orderd in a list. I would like users to be able to add symbols to their list from other content eg: news, trending symbols, symbol lookup.

There's a reference to $user->data in this Drupal8 article but I couldn't find more details on it.
https://www.webomelette.com/storing-user-data-such-preferences-drupal-8-using-userdata-service
The user_save api may work but I'm not sure how you would store this two-level data structure.
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_save/7.x

I could not find any contrib modules for storing this data privately other than Profile2 which I don't think would work for this kind of content.
I'm looking for Drupal APIs to store this data on a per-user basis.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [ECK](https://www.drupal.org/project/eck) and link it to the user using [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference). You'll need to some small custom coding to auto fill the entity reference field with the logged in user's id. Better yet, you can use [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) for a no code solution to autofill the entity reference with the logged in user ID.

Here is a [video on ECK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cu4h-xhwb2k) and for [entity reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AcVz8Thxq48).

Comment: interesting ... why not add the custom code also?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens sorry, my brain was stuck in D8 mode.

Comment: was, or is still?

Comment: was, forgot that Rules existed.